# How to introduce delay between tests in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, protractor, cucumber

I am exploring protractor tool with cucumber and test is executing super fast.. in order to know if really elements are getting clicked or not, I am using sleep() method but failing. I am also using another method wait() with expected conditions which is also failing.. In fact, I understood click() method on the link element itself is failing.. That is, unable to click on element which I desired, however when I print on console element is printing all its attributes and methods.

please find the code snippet as below;

```
When(/^I click on "(.*?)" link$/,  (callback) => {
    console.log("Clicking... ");
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(login.confirmInstructions), 5*1000, "Waiting for Confirmation link...");
    var confirmLink  = login.confirmInstructions;
    var isClickable  = EC.elementToBeClickable(confirmLink);
    browser.wait(isClickable, 10*1000, "Element clickable");
    confirmLink.click();

    browser.sleep(10*10000);
    login.confirmInstructions.click();
    //browser.wait(validateText(element(by.binding('myvar'))), 5000, "");
    //browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(confirmation.confirmScreen), 60*1000);
    console.log("waited");
    return callback;
});
```

What I am missing here.?

Comment: Its possible that the element you are clicking on is not the element that truly needs to be clicked. I have occasionally ran into problems where clicking the parent element does not work, but if I click a more specific child the click will register. Possibly something like this?

Comment: Also, instead of using a sleep to verify if the click happened, it would be better to expect() an action that would only happen if the click happened such as a text change or alert.

Comment: Try using browser.driver.sleep() instead of browser.sleep()

Comment: @DublinDev: I tried that and failed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood, the best way to wait for web elements in protractor is to use, wait() rather than sleep. However, I was looking either of the way (by using wait / sleep) to slow down the test execution, as it is useful while implementing test scenarios in order to recognize web elements. Finally, following method for now I am using it.. but still if there is a better way to handle please put your comments..

```
const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

and calling sleep from my function as:  `await sleep(2000);`

For now, I am able to move forward with writing tests.. I am also sure there is a better way in protractor API, yet to find it's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but if you just want to see if your "confirmInstructions" is clicked, you should use a debugger and set a breakpoint before the method

Comment: "use a debugger", meaning console.log().? yes, element is identifying but click is not taking place.. as I am seeing log statements before click and after click is printing. And also element is printing on console (printed to make sure it is not undefined)

Comment: in js, just write debugger in your code : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: Nothing got printed @Pierre on console. btw, it is typescript

Comment: console.log() is to print, debugger will just stop the code. After debugger you can go line by line

Comment: I introduced debugger and ran the test, but code didn't stop,test ran till the end.. :(

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't go through your method? no Idea here, sorry

Comment: Alright, thank you @Pierre. It is actually executing my method, as I am seeing console.log() statements.

Comment: just thinking about that : did you open the developer tools before you started your code?

Comment: test starts in its own chrome instance.. and tests run v.fast.. by the time dev tool opens, test execution finishing and browser instance close